# How do LVM Snapshots work on the PE level?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, lvm, lvm2

How do LVM Snapshots work on the PE level? What is stored where? What data is lost when the snapshot runs out of COW space?

(description + explanation below)

I was experimenting with LVM and snapshots on VirtualBox, and I am noticing some strange behavior. I wanted to see how a system would react under various situations, so I installed Lubuntu 13.04 on to a virtual machine with the LVM option checked. After it installed my system, I then added another 8GB drive to the virtual machine, used `vgcreate` to extend the Volume Group `lubuntu-vg` to `/dev/sdb`, and then took a snapshot of `lubuntu-vg/root` with `lvcreate`, with size 6.74G creating `lubuntu-vg/rootsnap` (note, the `lvdisplay` command logged below was ran before I created the snapshot)

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c4cee

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    16775167     8136705    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    16775167     8136704   8e  Linux LVM

Command (m for help): q

user@user-VirtualBox:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/lubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                lubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                JeyQ7Z-dtu1-Yr5R-hTTU-6Vya-Dr67-qSXwTf
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time lubuntu, 2013-05-02 18:09:41 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.73 GiB
  Current LE             1723
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/lubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                lubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                ZkyAxG-mFB0-zhDH-GjfK-CHlz-RbMc-ilumbj
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time lubuntu, 2013-05-02 18:09:41 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1020.00 MiB
  Current LE             255
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

user@user-VirtualBox:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               lubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  8
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               15.75 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              4033
  Alloc PE / Size       1978 / 7.73 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       2055 / 8.03 GiB
  VG UUID               2ZEhCz-Q988-oBAc-nE14-MdUs-j7un-2oicHD

user@user-VirtualBox:~$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               lubuntu-vg
  PV Size               7.76 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1986
  Free PE               8
  Allocated PE          1978
  PV UUID               OYCQrn-p7PH-4D52-4xRR-xphi-9DyL-Klys3t

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               lubuntu-vg
  PV Size               8.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2047
  Free PE               2047
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               ErizVU-o1Vf-73GO-Pkwf-PeM9-xoWo-snSmm2
```

I then downloaded a few updates to fill up `/var/cache/apt/archives`, and then powered down the system. To simulate a drive failure, I removed /dev/sdb from the VirtualBox settings, and booted the machine back up. It failed to mount because it couldn't find `lubuntu-vg/root`. At this point, I tried to figure out what the LE and PE configuration "looked like" for my system.

I tried to imagine what the layout of my LVM setup would look like; On `/dev/sda`, it would have allocated a few PEs at the beginning for the swap, then allocated the rest of the PEs to `lubuntu-vg/root`. Then I extended `lubuntu-vg` to `/dev/sdb`, and took a snapshot, which I imagined would allocate most of the PEs on `/dev/sdb`. My guess is that `lubuntu-vg/rootsnap` now uses the same PEs that `lubuntu-vg/root` did originally, and now `lubuntu-vg/root` (withe the cached .debs in `/var/cache/apt/archives`) uses a mixture of the old PEs, and the newly allocated PEs on `/dev/sdb` for COW purposes. So it made sense to me that when I removed `/dev/sdb` (supposedly with the COW PEs) the machine failed to boot because it couldn't find `lubuntu-vg/root`.

I then re-added `/dev/sdb`, booted up, and deleted the snapshot. At this point, I expected that if I were to remove `/dev/sdb` again the system would fail to boot, since the COW PEs were on that drive. However, when I tried this, the system is able to boot up successfully and the .debs were still in  `/var/cache/apt/archives`, despite `/dev/sdb` not being attached.

How is this possible? I thought that the COW PEs were on `/dev/sdb`, which I removed. Did LVM move the COW PEs to `/dev/sda` when I removed the snapshot, or does some other fancy movements when I create the snapshot?

One thought I had was that maybe when LVM allocates PEs, it does virtually and doesn't actually physically reserve them when a LV is created, allowing LV's PEs to be interleaved between each other. If that is the case, why wasn't the system able to boot when `/dev/sdb` was removed? Wouldn't the COW PEs be on `/dev/sda` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the snapshot, you allocate PEs to hold the COW'd blocks.  If it fills up or is not accessible, it is the snapshot that dies, not the origin.  Your system should have been able to boot fine without /dev/sdb since the snapshot is not required to boot.  If it didn't, then there's a bug somewhere.

Also you don't have to imagine where the PEs are allocated, you can run `pvdisplay -m` to see.